# Convert Seconds To Time Stamp

Tags: swift, xcode, time

I am using Swift to calculate an array of times to an average number of times in hundredth seconds. The resulting average is output of the total hundredth seconds.

***ex: Total Hundredth Seconds 111***

How can I convert these hundredth seconds to

(minutes) : (seconds) . (hundredth second)

(max 60) : (max 60) . (max 100)

***ex: 00:01.11***

I am using this to convert array to total hundredth seconds:

```
let timeToSecondsArray = valueLast20.map{
     i -> Int in
     let timeString = (i as AnyObject).components(separatedBy: ":")
     let minute = Int(timeString[0])
     let second = Int(timeString[1])
     let hundredthseconds = Int(timeString[2])
     let minuteToSec = minute! * 3600
     let secondToSec = second! * 60
     let totalSeconds = minuteToSec + secondToSec + hundredthseconds!
     return totalSeconds
}

let seconds: Int = timeToSecondsArray.reduce(0, {x, y in x + y})/timeToSecondsArray.count
let one = String(format: "%02ld", seconds/3600)
let two = String(format: "%02ld", (seconds%3600)/60)
let three = String(format: "%02ld", ((seconds%3600)%60))
self.averageTime.text = "\(one):\(two).\(three)"
```

Comment: what is your question? *"(whatever to word for this is)"* -> milliseconds

Comment: 111 seconds is not 1 minute 11 seconds.

Comment: Okay, lets start over: it is not actually millisecond but "hundredth second" (centisecond). And what you are doing wrong is assuming that the input of 111 is seconds, it is not, those are 111 hundredth of a second meaning one full second and 11 more hundredth of a second.

Comment: @WillMays That is NOT how Apple Stopwatch is timed.  The Apple Stopwatch format is 00:00.00 (notice the decimal) and represents minutes, seconds, and hundreths of a second,  not milliseconds.  And what chris told you is correct, 111 seconds is 1 minute and 51 seconds.

Comment: @luk2302 Ah ok I understand now, I have updated the question

Comment: @ChrisAllwein updated the question

Comment: @luk2302 What would I need to change in my code to accomplish this?

Comment: @ChrisAllwein What would I need to change in my code to accomplish this?

Comment: Your code does not make much sense based solely on the fact that `timeToSecondsArray` does not represent seconds. What is your input data?

Comment: @luk2302 the input array is multiple times like follows: [“00:01:24”, “00:00:96”] there will be 20 times. I need to change timeToSecondsArray too because it does not represent hundredths it still represents seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let valueLast20 = ["01:03:24", "01:00:98"]

let hundredthSecondsArray = valueLast20.map{
    i -> Int in
    let timeString = (i as AnyObject).components(separatedBy: ":")
    let minute = Int(timeString[0])
    let second = Int(timeString[1])
    let hundredthSeconds = Int(timeString[2])!
    let minuteToHundredth = minute! * 60 * 100
    let secondToHundredth = second! * 100
    let totalSeconds = minuteToHundredth + secondToHundredth + hundredthSeconds
    return totalSeconds
}

let hundredth: Int = hundredthSecondsArray.reduce(0, +) / hundredthSecondsArray.count
let one = String(format: "%02ld", hundredth / 100 / 60)
let two = String(format: "%02ld", (hundredth / 100 % 60))
let three = String(format: "%02ld", (hundredth % 100))
print("\(one):\(two).\(three)")
```

> 01:02.11